# Entity Framework Pre-Generated Views

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

I added pre-generated views for my model as described here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx

Everything seems to be working in terms of compilation and the code generation, but I'm not sure if EF is actually using my pre-generated views, since the first ObjectQuery is still taking 3-4 seconds to execute (before even generating the SQL).

How can I be sure that EF is using the pre-generated views?

Comment: Same issue for me, but with pre-generated views it becomes even slower, by 200ms approximately in average for 10 measurements.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, but I got this far: you can set a breakpoint in the constructor of the generated views class. It will be hit. You can also set a breakpoint in one of the GetViewx() methods. It will be hit when you query the corresponding table.

I'm using POCO's which are in another project/assembly than the generated context. The generated views are in the same assembly as the context. First I though it wasn't hit either, so I was searching and searching for a way to wire them up. The best I got was to use the ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(...) method. But the breakpoints are still hit even when I do not explicitly wire up the assembly (I just found that out).

Am I really 100% sure the generated views are used? No, since I also have a little delay with a fairly small model. But fairly sure? Yeah, as much as I can see.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using EF 5 and ran into the same issues as you.  Difference is for me I have to use the ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(...) method to get it to hit the breakpoints in the views class, when I omit that explicit wiring, they don't get called, and I verified this in DotTrace.  Don't know if this is a bug or what.